# Нужно создать mock объект который будет имплементировать несколько интерфейсов

Tags: php, phpunit

Нужно удовлетворить этому условию:

```
if ($entity instanceof EditorAttributes) {
    // ....
}
```

`$entity` - не существует ещё класса который бы создавал объект удовлетворяющий условию.
Нужно как-то создать mock объект чтобы в unit тесте пройти дальше.

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit умеет создавать Mock'и на основе интерфейсов, что называется, "из коробки". Для этого, в базовом классе теста существует специальный метод [`TestCase::getMock`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L1582).

Например, для создания Mock'а реализующего ваш интерфейс можно использовать вот такой код:

```
class FooTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testFoo()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock('\EditorAttributes');
        $this->assertTrue($mock instanceof \EditorAttributes);
    }
}
```

Если же вам нужно, чтобы Mock реализовывал больше одного интерфейса, вы можете передать в `TestCase::getMock` массив с именами целевых интерфейсов:

```
class FooTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testFoo()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock(['\EditorAttributes', '\ReaderAttributes']);
        $this->assertTrue($mock instanceof \EditorAttributes);
        $this->assertTrue($mock instanceof \ReaderAttributes);
    }
}
```